# Why resting Unity Interface? Почему сбрасывается Unity окружение?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, interface, reset

Previously, it was when I closed my KTorrent. Folder on the desktop and changed the subject became gray, and the inscription underneath in black letters. Folder Nautilus became not rounded as usual, but ostrouglymi with gray.
Now, it happens less frequently. If earlier it was not understandable, because of what was dropped on the topic of unity windows interface gnome.To now it happens every time you close your browser Opera, and if at that time I copy something from disk to disk, then copying is reset, and folders that have been open, too closed.
Nasty bug.
In general the system has become more convenient to use than 10.04, there is at least completely update the system get out different bugs.
There is one single bug that climbs into his eyes, hoping not to me alone, so please change this nonsense as soon as possible. As long as we use the buggy system? Hopefully in the future, the Ubuntu will not always be associated with the test system, and when something becomes stable.
I use a distro Ubuntu 11.10. Nautilus 3.2.1 version.
I connect third-party repositories, but without them, just discharged standard theme Unity. That is to cure this problem and I hooked up an additional repository for Unity, but it did not solve the problem.

Раньше так было, когда я закрывал KTorrent. Папки на рабочем меняли тему и становились серыми, а надписи под ними чёрными буквами. Папки Nautilus становились не закруглёнными как обычно, а остроуглыми с серым цветом.
Теперь так происходит стало реже. Если раньше это было не объяснимо, из за чего сбрасывалась тема unity на интерфейс окон gnome.То теперь это происходит при каждом закрытии браузера Opera, причём если в это время я что то копирую с диска на диск, то копирование сбрасывается, и папки которые были открыты, тоже закрываются.
Неприятный баг. 
Вообщем системой стало пользоваться более удобнее, чем в 10.04, там хоть полностью обновишь систему вылезают разные баги.
Тут же один единственный баг, который лезет в глаза, надеюсь не мне одному, поэтому прошу изменить эту ерунду как можно скорее. Доколе мы будем пользоваться глючной системой? Надеюсь Убунту в будущем не будет ассоциироваться с вечно тестируемой системой,а когда нибудь станет стабильной.
Я использую дистрибутив Ubuntu 11.10. Nautilus 3.2.1 версия.
Подключаю сторонние репозитории, но и без них так же сбрасывалась стандартная тема Unity. Именно, чтобы вылечить эту проблему я и подключил дополнительный репозиторий для Unity, но это проблему не решило.

Sorry,that no english. But for me in russian easy explain this problem, And i hope here reading by russian. If writen in english i am not scared,if by russian - just by lucky.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to AskUbuntu - since most visitors communicate here via english, you should use Google Translate to convert from english to russian and russian to english. Привет и добро пожаловать AskUbuntu - так как большинство посетителей здесь общаться через английски, вы должны использовать Google Translate для преобразования с английского на русский и с русского на английский.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 10.04 or something else? Are you using a special version of Nautilus (downloaded from somewhere for example)? Please include your answers in your question by clicking on "edit".

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I think you have a bug. You should report it: type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to be able to launch a command, and then type apport-bug nautilus and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Wait some time, and then Click on "Send report". Thank you for your help!

Comment: I do how you written: type apport-bug nautilus and press Enter. Then go checking and collection of information, next show "It is not original distributiv Ubuntu". So it did not help. But thank for new information about commands in Ubuntu.